# Pandas dataframe shows values as 'NaN'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I tried to put columns on the dataframe like following;

[image: after I checked it, tried to add columns]

[image: but all contents changed into 'NaN's. how can I solve it?]

Comment: if you use `pd.read_csv()`  , f is already a dataframe, just check f

Comment: Adding onto Steven's - `f.columns = [your, values]` should do it.

Comment: something wrong when I upload captured images. sorry for interrupting. After I tried to do like in the first image,  I figured out all contents changed into 'NaN's. How can I solve it?

Comment: tried to type f = pd.read_csv("tbsm_trdar_ncm_cnsmp.csv", header=None), and changed the columns name. I solved it. Thanks guys!

Comment: @JohnGalt, please post your answer as the solution so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first line of your code, the :

```
f = pd.read_csv("tbsm_trdar_ncm_cnsmp.csv")
```

the variable 'f' is already a DataFrame which equals to your 'df1', so you don't need to write the second line:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(f)
```

And if you do this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(f, columns=[...])
```

Actually, it tries to create a new DataFrame from f. It tries to copy the provided column names from f to the new df1. In this case, there's no column called 'TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CN_NM', etc. So the df1 shows NaNs.

If you just want to rename the DataFrame columns, you can do this:

```
f = pd.read_csv(
        "tbsm_trdar_ncm_cnsmp.csv", 
        header=None, names=['TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CN_NM', ...])
```

or

```
f = pd.read_csv("tbsm_trdar_ncm_cnsmp.csv", header=None)
f.columns = ['TRDAR_CD', 'TRDAR_CN_NM', ...]
```

I add the parameter 'header=None' in the .read_csv function because it seems that your csv file doesn't contain the header.